# Youtube analytics API - different information in case of owning a channel?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, channel-api, youtube-analytics-api

I want to retrieve some data from youtube channels, which I am not the owner of. I have the following questions:

- List item 1) Are there proposed ways to do this and
- List item 2) is the information I can access different from the one that I can access as a channel owner?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? what data are you referring to? Metrics? Comments? Videos? Did you try querying the Youtube API using your Youtube account and then logging out and querying it as non-owner?

Comment: I have not tried anything so far. I do not own a channel and so I wonder, whether I can query the same data as I could as a channel owner. Can anybody help with this?